# How to detect if a url is opened in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, **I want to detect if a url is opened and to get its ID**.
The url is "https://www.youtube.com/*" (the * is the variable part of the url) and I would like to detect, when the popup's button is clicked, if the url is opened.

I already tried this code:

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(windows){
  windows.forEach(function(window){
    window.tabs.forEach(function(tab){
      //for each url check if the url is "https://www.youtube.com/*"
      if(tab.url === "https://www.youtube.com/*") {
       console.log("youtube detected!")
      }
    });
  });
});
```

but, if the url is like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ", it won't log "youtube detected!" (so it won't work). I think the problem is in the "/*" of the url but I don't know how to detect url's variable parts after the "https://www.youtube.com/". How could I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: you should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string "StartsWith" another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/how-to-check-if-a-string-startswith-another-string)

Comment: Instead of chrome.windows use `chrome.tabs.query({url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch*'}, tabs => { console.log(tabs); })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone, this works:

```
chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true},function(windows){
  windows.forEach(function(window){
    window.tabs.forEach(function(tab){

      //for each url check if the url is "https://www.youtube.com/*"
      if(tab.url.startsWith("https://www.youtube.com/")) {
       console.log("youtube detected!");
      }

    });
  });
});
```

I also found this way:

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: "https://www.youtube.com/*"}, tabs => {
  console.log("youtube detected!");
  //let url = tabs[0].url; use this to get the url
});
```

if you have a better solution, please let me know about that!

Answer (score 0):

Here u go

```
if (tab.url.contains("youtube") {
   console.log("youtube detected!")
}
```